# How do I fix this infinite loop, and other problems in my code?

Tags: c++, calculator

Here is the link to my assignment: http://prnt.sc/e9q619

The default in the switch if fulfilled becomes an infinite loop, and also I'm having trouble doing the other important notes from the assignment. When I went to another tutor, he attempted to tell me to use vectors and strings in ways we haven't learned in class yet, so it is okay if the 'c' and 'x' to use isn't fixed.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int Num1 = 1;
    int Num2 = 1;
    char operation;
    int answer = 1;

    cout << "Here is a four function integer calculator." << endl;
    cout << "Please use 'x' to exit the calculator, and 'c' to clear the calculator in the operator space. E.G. ""1 x 3"" would exit the calculator." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the first number, operation, and second number in respective order, separated by a space each." << endl;


    while (i > 0)
    {
        cin >> Num1 >> operation >> Num2;
        switch (operation)
        {
        case '+':
            answer = Num1 + Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = Num1 - Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            answer = Num1 * Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            if (Num2 == 0 && operation != 'x') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                answer = Num1 / Num2;
                cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'c':
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 'x':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You entered a wrong number, operator, or form for the entire operation" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Think about your loop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what I did was I checked each of the inputs individually and wrote an input validation statement.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int Num1 = 1;
    int Num2 = 1;
    char operation;
    int answer = 1;

    cout << "Here is a four function integer calculator." << endl;
    cout << "Please use 'x' to exit the calculator, and 'c' to clear the calculator in the operator space. E.G. ""1 x 3"" would exit the calculator." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the first number, operation, and second number in respective order, separated by a space each." << endl;


    while (i > 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter Num1: " << endl;
        cin >> Num1;
        cout << "Enter operation: " << endl;
        cin >> operation;
        cout << "Enter Num2: " << endl;
        cin >> Num2;

        while (operation != '+' && operation != '-' && operation != '*' && operation != '/')
        {
            cout << "You Suck. Try again." << endl;
            cout << "Enter Num1: "  << endl;
            cin >> Num1;
            cout << "Enter operation: " << endl;
            cin >> operation;
            cout << "Enter Num2: " << endl;
            cin >> Num2;
        }

        switch (operation)
        {
        case '+':
            answer = Num1 + Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = Num1 - Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            answer = Num1 * Num2;
            cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            if (Num2 == 0 && operation != 'x') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                answer = Num1 / Num2;
                cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
            }
            break;
        case 'c':
            system("cls");
            break;
        case 'x':
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You entered a wrong number, operator, or form for the entire operation" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "The solution is: " << answer << "." << endl;
}
```